# Calculating square-roots with CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to do a square-root function in the calc() function of my CSS file? I've read that calc() only supports the basic operators like + - * and /.

Ideally, it'd look something like this:

```
width: calc(50% - (sqrt(7200))px);
```

If calc() do not have a sqrt function, what can I do?

Comment: I don't think a sqrt operation is possible. But sqrt(7200) is just a number. Why dont you calculate it by hand?

Comment: Why do you need to find a square root in CSS?

Comment: If you are using sqrt, you will obviously use variables right? Because if it was a constant, it can be calculated by hand.

Comment: I cannot think of a single reason to need square roots in the design of a webpage.

Comment: @sevenseacat maybe animation calculations?

Comment: Animation is behaviour, not presentation. Doesn't belong in CSS.

Comment: @sevenseacat: But animations are for show, right? How is that not presentation?

Comment: @sevenseacat https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: Animation is not presentation? Ok...

Comment: OK, basically, I have a rectangular <div>, I am trying to position that rectangle accurately relative to a circle - I am trying to make the corner of the rectangle touch the circumference of the circle, at a specific point. Through doing some trig, I determined I need to find the square root of a number, which I didn't want to simply type in integers because 1) it's not accurate 2) it doesn't look good 3) it's not elegant

Comment: The advantage of a preprocessing system is that if you make the radius a variable to fit changes in screen sizes, you can have the preprocessor change the CSS positioning.  However, perhaps there is something else you can do with `<canvas>`.

Comment: in IE9 this caused the browser to stop working *background-position-x: calc(100% - 2px);*

Comment: @sevenseacat Anything involving calculating triangles would need sqrt, and that is pure presentation, nothing to do with animations.

Comment: Here's my square-root-needing purpose: I want a linear gradient that will obscure the top-left and bottom-right parts of a `div` to make a perfect parallelogram at a certain angle. Also, the `div`'s width is `100vw` and its height is `calc(100vh - 60px)`, so the square root needs to happen in the `calc()` and not in a preprocessor.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/sqrt

this article says, sqrt() does exist in the calc()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Square root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/sqrt)

Coming here to say that the square root is now a CSS function working in CSS, and is already used in most browsers today. It was recently implemented.

```css
div {
  width: calc(sqrt(36) * 10px);
  /* sqrt(36) will be 6, so 6 * 10px will be 60px */

  height: calc(sqrt(25) * 10px);
  /* sqrt(25) will be 5, so 5 * 10px will be 50px */
}

/* other stuff */
div { background: red;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;border: 10px solid #fcc;border-radius: 20px;font-family: sans-serif;color: #eee;display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;}
```

```html
<div>I'm a div</div>
```

---

### Cube root

If you need to, you can specify the cube root like this (which also works in most browsers):

```css
div {
  width: calc(pow(125, 1 / 3) * 10px);
  /* cubed root of 125 will be 5, so 5 * 10px will be 50px */

  height: calc(pow(64, 1 / 3) * 10px);
  /* cubed root of 64 will be 4, so 4 * 10px will be 40px */
}

/* other stuff */
div { background: red;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;border: 10px solid #fcc;border-radius: 20px;font-family: sans-serif;color: #eee;display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;}
```

```html
<div>I'm a div</div>
```

*Mathematically speaking, we can use the cube root of a number as the number itself raised to 1/3, and the same thing with the square root of a number being the number raised to 1/2, and so on*
So we use the [pow css function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pow).

---

### [Hypotenuse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hypot)

But maybe you're here looking for this to do some hypotenuse, as we also have a function for this already working in most browsers!

Unlike sqrt and pow, the hypotenuse accepts units.

I will use the famous right triangle `3, 4, 5` to exemplify. If I put the legs of the triangle as 3 and 4, the hypotenuse has to be 5. In the example below I used the legs as `30px`, `40px`, so the hypotenuse will be `50px`.

```css
div {  
  width: hypot(30px, 40px);
  height: hypot(30px, 40px);
}

/* other stuff */
div { background: red;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;border: 10px solid #fcc;border-radius: 20px;font-family: sans-serif;color: #eee;display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;}
```

```html
<div>I'm a div</div>
```

---

Hope this helps! ;D

Also thanking [mountarreat answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49461883/6227108) for the workaround here as I used this while I didn't have these css functions available, and also for learning a technique for solving the square root that I had never learned before haha

Answer (score 29):

As others suggested, if dealing with repeat values, just use a preprocessor, or copy/paste if from the calculator directly, e.g. sqrt(2) = 1.4142135623730950488016887242097.

But **if you really have to use a dynamic way** to calculate the square root in CSS dynamically and without JS, there is of course. While a precision of 5 seems enough for most cases, for the number 7200 in your example we should bump it up to a precision of 9+, unless you could make an initial guess, which is closer to the result, but that’s out of question for now.

But without optimization this will bloat your document by 50.000+ extra characters, if using the generated output from the other answer/suggestion.

Since we use it dynamically, we ought to use CSS variables, which limits the browser compatibility a bit, but it already has a global support of about 88% by now (Mar/2018).

**Here we go:**

```css
#test {
    --number: 7200;
    --guess01: calc((var(--number) + ( var(--number) / var(--number))) / 2);
    --guess02: calc((var(--guess01) + ( var(--number) / var(--guess01))) / 2);
    --guess03: calc((var(--guess02) + ( var(--number) / var(--guess02))) / 2);
    --guess04: calc((var(--guess03) + ( var(--number) / var(--guess03))) / 2);
    --guess05: calc((var(--guess04) + ( var(--number) / var(--guess04))) / 2);
    --guess06: calc((var(--guess05) + ( var(--number) / var(--guess05))) / 2);
    --guess07: calc((var(--guess06) + ( var(--number) / var(--guess06))) / 2);
    --guess08: calc((var(--guess07) + ( var(--number) / var(--guess07))) / 2);
    --guess09: calc((var(--guess08) + ( var(--number) / var(--guess08))) / 2);
    --guess10: calc((var(--guess09) + ( var(--number) / var(--guess09))) / 2);

    width:calc(50% - (var(--guess10) * 1px));
    height:200px;
    background: black;
    padding:20px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Width is 50% - sqrt(7200) in px</div>
```

Comment: This is a really good answer which actually let's you use square roots calculations with CSS variables which would be useful for dynamic calculations, most noticeably spacing and fonts across responsive designs. Nicely done. Would love to see the same for exponents.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a preprocessing system for CSS. For example, you can use [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) and [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/). Compass has a [sqrt](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/math/) function.

Why?  Perhaps for print styling, or maybe to experiment with the golden mean.

Answer (score 9):

According to spec here http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc

> The calc() function allows mathematical expressions with addition (‘+’), subtraction (‘-’), multiplication (‘*’), and division (‘/’) to be used as component values. The ‘calc()’ expression represents the result of the mathematical calculation it contains, using standard operator precedence rules. It can be used wherever `<length>`, `<frequency>`, `<angle>`, `<time>`, `<number>`, or `<integer>` values are allowed. Components of a ‘calc()’ expression can be literal values, ‘attr()’ or ‘calc()’ expressions, or  values that resolve to one of the preceding types.

So you can't calc square roots directly in css for now.. unfortunately :(

Answer (score 5):

I believe that you are interested in dynamically calculating the square root of a number. Contrary to popular belief, you should be able to approximate the square root of a number using only calc. Unfortunately, should is a world of a difference between reality. In reality, or chrome at least, the greatest thing in css, calc, is annoyingly limited in being incapable of doing multiplication or division with 2 variable multiplicands. In said perfect world, the following would work. Click **Run Code Snippet**.

```js
var nth=document.getElementById('nth'),
    percision=document.getElementById('percision'),
    counter=document.getElementById('counter'),
    input=document.getElementById('input'),
    output=document.getElementById('output');

percision.oninput = function(){
    counter.innerText = percision.value;
};
//var base = "(X+A/X)/2";
var base = 'calc(calc(X + calc(A / X)) / 2)';
(nth.onchange = percision.onchange =
input.onchange = function(){
    nth.value = parseInt(nth.value);
    counter.innerText = percision.value;
    var cur=base, i=percision.value;
    while (i--){
        cur = cur.replace(/X/g, base);
    }
    cur = cur.replace(/A/g, input.value)
             .replace(/X/g, '1');
    output.value = cur;
})();
```

```css
body, body *:not(script) {
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#nth {
  width: 64px;
  text-align: center;
}
nthText {
  visibility: hidden; /* not yet implemented */
  display: none;
}
#percision {
 width: 192px;
}
#input {
 width: calc(100% - 154px);
}
textarea {
 max-height: 64px;
 min-width: calc(100% - 10px);
 width: calc(100% - 10px);
 max-width: calc(100% - 10px);
 white-space: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center">CSS sqrt function generator</h1>
<nthText>Nth root: <input id="nth" type="text" placeholder="2" value="2" /><br /></nthText>
Percision: <sub>(min)</sub> <input id="percision" type="range" min="1" max="20" value="5" /> <sub>(max)</sub> (<span id="counter">5</span> repetitions)<br />
CSS to be rooted: <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="calc(calc(5vw * 5vh) - 3em)" value="calc(calc(5vw * 5vh) - 3em)" /><br />
<textarea id="output" resize="x" rows="4" onclick="this.select()"></textarea><br />
(click on the textarea above and press <b>Ctrl</b><small>+</small><b>C</b> to copy)
```

Browser Support for this method: IE9+ (because all that is needed is the calc function)